# Passing file args in a bash

Tags: java, bash, jar

The bash script is supposed to do one and one thing; ie; feeding the list of file names one after the other separated by a space  to the jar file.

Here is part of the script

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++) do
java <myjar.jar>file$i
done
```

what i expect the `java <myjar.jar> file$i` line to look like while executing the script is

```
java <myjar.jar> file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's bash, just do this:

```
java <myjar.jar> file{1..5}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this might be to leverage the automatic shell filename expansion:

```
java myjar.jar file[1-5]
```

The above assumes that the files exist in the filesystem beforehand. Or, you can do something like:

```
java myjar.jar `for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo file$i; done`
```

If you have a large number of items, the `seq` command will help:

```
java myjar.jar `for i in $(seq 500); do echo file$i; done`
```

Comment: Normally i is gonna be very big/huge; so the first one is a reasonable way to go i guess.... Many  thanks!

Comment: @deepseefan: See my updated answer, which also works if you have more than 9 files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a listn
for n in $(seq $2 $3) ; do
    listn=("${listn[@]}" $n)
done

java "$1" "${listn[@]}"
```

And call the script with three arguments:

```
./the_script myjar.jar 1 5
```

The first argument is your jar name, the next is the first number in your sequence, the last is the final number.